# Read a csv file and fill in database with it's data in django application

Tags: python, django

in my Django application, i created a form which permit user to upload csv file.
What i want is when user upload the csv file, the contained data is read and database is filled in with them.
It works but not correctly. data are saved as tuples.

[image: Look the first row]

Here's my code

**forms.py**

```
class SupplierCSVForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SuplierCsv
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('slug',)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def l_supplier(request):
    suppliers_list = Supplier.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(suppliers_list, 3, 2)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    suppliers = paginator.get_page(page)

    # Supplier csv form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SupplierCSVForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():

            uploaded_file = request.FILES['csvfile']
            with open('f.csv', 'wb') as destination:
                for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
                    destination.close()
            #csvfile = io.TextIOWrapper(open('f.csv', 'rb'))

            with open('f.csv', 'r') as the_source:
                source_reader = csv.reader(sthe_source)
                next(source_reader)
                for Name, Email, Contact, City, Website, Activity, Cc, slug in source_reader:

                    new_supplier = Supplier()
                    new_supplier.name=Name,
                    new_supplier.email=Email,
                    new_supplier.contact=Contact,
                    new_supplier.city=City,
                    new_supplier.website=Website,
                    new_supplier.activity=Activity,
                    new_supplier.cc=Cc,
                    new_supplier.slug=slug,
                    new_supplier.save()

            return redirect('good:l_good')

    else:
        form = SupplierCSVForm()

    context = {
    'suppliers': suppliers,
    'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'supplier/l_supplier.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have unnecessary commas at the end of your lines:

```
new_supplier.name=Name,
```

should be

```
new_supplier.name=Name
```

Python thinks that you are creating a tuple
i.e. x, == (x,)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the commas where you are assigning the `new_supplier` objects. Python converts your string objects into tuples if there are any trailing commas.